# How to configure JPA security for Quarkus (Getting NullPointerException)?

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache

9.1 as per my `gradle.properties` file:

```
#Gradle properties
#Wed Oct 28 14:48:17 EDT 2020
quarkusPluginVersion=1.9.1.Final
quarkusPlatformArtifactId=quarkus-universe-bom
quarkusPlatformGroupId=io.quarkus
quarkusPlatformVersion=1.9.1.Final
org.gradle.logging.level=INFO
```

In my `application.properties` I have:

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=mssql
%dev.quarkus.datasource.username=foo
%dev.quarkus.datasource.password=bar
%dev.quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://xxxxxx;databaseName=xxxxxx
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=none
```

My entity:

```
import io.quarkus.elytron.security.common.BcryptUtil;
import io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.PanacheEntity;
import io.quarkus.security.jpa.Password;
import io.quarkus.security.jpa.UserDefinition;
import io.quarkus.security.jpa.Username;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "my_user")
@UserDefinition
public class MyUser extends PanacheEntity {
    @Username
    public String username;
    @Password
    public String password;

    /**
     * Adds a new user in the database
     * @param username the user name
     * @param password the unencrypted password (it will be encrypted with bcrypt)
     */
    public static void add(String username, String password) {
        MyUser myUser = new MyUser();
        myUser.username = username;
        myUser.password = BcryptUtil.bcryptHash(password);
        myUser.persist();
    }
}
```

The init code:

```
import com.xxxxxx.MyUser;
import io.quarkus.runtime.StartupEvent;

import javax.enterprise.event.Observes;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

@Singleton
public class Startup {
    @Transactional
    public void loadUsers(@Observes StartupEvent evt) {
        // reset and load all test users
        MyUser.deleteAll();
        MyUser.add("test", "test");
        MyUser.add("user", "user");
    }
}
```

But when I start Quarkus I get...

```
2020-11-09 15:59:50,320 ERROR [io.qua.dep.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain] (main) Failed to start quarkus: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.security.jpa.deployment.QuarkusSecurityJpaProcessor#configureJpaAuthConfig threw an exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.quarkus.security.jpa.deployment.JpaSecurityDefinition.getFieldOrMethod(JpaSecurityDefinition.java:81)
    at io.quarkus.security.jpa.deployment.JpaSecurityDefinition.<init>(JpaSecurityDefinition.java:76)
    at io.quarkus.security.jpa.deployment.QuarkusSecurityJpaProcessor.configureJpaAuthConfig(QuarkusSecurityJpaProcessor.java:107)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:936)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2046)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1578)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:479)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a variable for roles (with anotation @Roles) in your User entity.

Here you are tutorial from [quarkus.pro](https://quarkus.pro/guides/security-jpa#defining-our-user-entity) it is point 4.

> This indicates the comma-separated list of roles added to the target Principal representation attributes.

Comment: Thanks I figure it out! But nowhere does that error indicate that. I didn't need roles but I added the column anyways. Just not using it I guess...